# Memory usage during and after drop_duplicates()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am working with a data frame that takes up roughly 2 Gb of memory (according to htop) with dimensions (6287475,19). The data frame is heterogeneous in data type, which probably does not matter. Immediately after loading the data frame I drop duplicate rows using the command

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
```

During the execution of this command memory usage jumps to about 7 Gb. After the command is completed the memory reduced to almost 5 Gb, which is more than twice the memory required to store a single instance of the data frame. If I then delete the data frame with `del df` memory usage decreases to about 3 Gb.

The behavior is the same if I do the following:

```
df2 = df.drop_duplicates
del df
del df2
```

Running `gc.collect()` does nothing and memory usage returns to its baseline level after terminating the python session. Does this look like a memory leak? Has anyone seen similar behavior?

Environment:

- 64-bit linux
- python 2.7.7 (64-bit)
- pandas 0.14.1
- numpy 1.8.2
- Ipython 2.2.0 (behavior same for cpython)

Comment: passing inplace does not mean things are actually inplace, in fact this MUST make a copy in order to operate properly. (it also constructs a boolean array to index, so that is the same size as your df, but boolean dtype). So I would say your memory usage is about as expected. Note that python doesn't necessarily return (and usually does not) memory to the OS. No leaking here.

Comment: What should *should* do in order to have a lower memory usage is this (assuming you are starting with a csv). chunk-read with a reasonable chunksize (say 1M), then drop-duplicates on that chunk (depending on where your dups are this may remove a lot or just a little of the dups). Then concat the chunks. The drop_duplicates again.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff. I will take your advice and perform chunk-wise duplicate dropping. Cheers!

Comment: Another suggestion, if possible for you, is working with Polars which can make larger-than-memory operations